# Find interval between two hours

Tags: javascript

I want to caluculate amout time slots avalible based on these inputs:

```
    let start = req.body.start; //Start of hour
    let end = req.body.end; // End of hour
    let interval = req.body.interval // Interval that the timeslots are going to be set
```

So with the input of this:

```
start = 11:00
end = 19:00
interval = 30 //minutes
dif = end - start // as int not time
```

I want the output to be:

```
[11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 
 13:30, 14:00, 14:30, 15:00, 15:30,
 16:00, 16:30, 17:00, 17:30, 18:00, 
 18:30, 19:00]
```

in string format of course

found a semi working suliton with the interval of 20 minutes:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < dif; i++) {
      let hourArray = [];
      let hour = parseInt(start) + i;
      for (let j = 0; j < 60 / interval; j++) {
        let hourTime = `${hour}:${interval * j}`;
        if (j === 0) {
          hourTime = `${hour}:00`;
        }
        hourArray.push(hourTime);
      }
      console.log(hourArray);
    }
```

Comment: So what did you try to solve this? - [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense at all. What happens if start is `11:17`? Do you expect timespans like `11:17, 11:47, ...`

Comment: i presented you a simple question, it really doesnt matter. these will be invalid

Comment: Without giving you the whole answer, here's what I would do: 1) write two functions that convert the time in HH:MM to just minutes since midnight and back to HH:MM. 2) Start with the start time 3) add current time to the result 4) increase the time by interval until the time in minutes is greater than end time 5) repeat from 3)

Comment: thank you for the guidance. Can you check the code again and give me some tips?

Comment: Your code is not doing what I wrote. avalibleTimeSlots is not defined anywhere. It doesn't look like it's solving the problem at all. Please start anew, and consider my previous comment.

Comment: can you check again now, have update it

Comment: You're still trying to do math separately on hours and minutes, which is a worse idea than just working on minutes, as it will generate a lot of special cases.

Comment: okei i will get back to you :)

Comment: Can you alaborate on the first instruction? what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can start by converting hh:mm timeslots to minutes from midnight, we then get the start time and endtime in minutes - `startMins` and `endMins`

We'll then use a for loop to create each timeslot, adding `interval` minutes for each iteration.

Finally we'll output by converting each timeslot to hh:mm format.

```js
function hhMMToMinutes(hhmm) {
    const [hours, mins] = hhmm.split(':').map(Number);
    return hours * 60 + mins;
}

function minutesToHHMM(minutes) {
    const hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    const mins = minutes % 60;
    return (hours + '').padStart(2, '0') + ':' + (mins + '').padStart(2, '0')
}

function getTimeSlots(start, end, interval) {
    const startMins = hhMMToMinutes(start);
    const endMins = hhMMToMinutes(end);
    const result = [];
    for (let mins = startMins; mins <= endMins; mins += interval) {
        result.push(minutesToHHMM(mins))
    }
    return result;
}

console.log('Timeslots:', getTimeSlots('11:00', '19:00', 30))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```